# Which table is correct Database Design?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, database-design

**Option 1:**

```
Country     |   Risk Category |    Value
USA         |      Health     |    0.75
USA         |      Market     |    0.66
USA         |    Technology   |    0.35
```

---

**Option 2:**

```
Country     | Health Risk | Market Risk | Technology Risk
USA         |     0.75    |      0.66   |      0.35
```

**Option 1:** allows for new risk categories to be dynamically added without needing to add columns when changes occur, but I'll have to run algorithms to find the values I'm looking for as it doesn't work well with LINQ.

**Option 2:** is easier to work with in entity framework as everything is scaffolded out. however, the database needs to change every time a new category is added. Also, there could potentially be 200+ columns.

Which option is the best for long-term success and maintainability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, neither are optimal for long-term & maintainability, but if I'd had to choose I'd go for Option 2.

Since you have a many to many relationship between the country entity and the risk entity I'd separate the information a bit more and do it like this.

Country

```
ID          |     Name    | 
1           |     USA     |    
2           |    CANADA   |
```

Risk

```
Id        |      Name     |
1         |     Health    |
2         |     Market    |
3         |   Technology  |
```

CountryRisk

```
CountryId |  RiskId  |  Value  | 
1         |     1    |   0.75  |
1         |     2    |   0.66  |
1         |     3    |   0.35  |
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 2.

If every country is always going to have a Health Risk, Market Risk and Technology Risk - You'll never risk repeating data. Databases should **never** repeat data.

I honestly can't see any benefits to Option 1 over Option 2.

Comment: Thanks, I agree! As a bonus question. How does a junior software developer, with limited database-design experience convince a senior DBA. To go with option 2, Instead of their option 1 design?

Comment: I'd say do some research and see if people have had similar experiences. In my experience, being a somewhat junior software developer myself, that you'd be fighting an uphill battle trying to tell a senior developer they did something wrong. :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'd say, I've been having the same experience as you lol